# MomentJs gives wrong month

Tags: javascript, angular, time, ionic2, momentjs

[Momentjs](https://momentjs.com) gives wrong month.

```
const time = moment("2300","hhmm").format("HH:mm");
const weekDay = moment().weekday(2).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
const notification =  moment(weekDay + " " + time, "DD/HH/YYYY HH:mm");
console.log(notification);
```

Give:

```
Object
_a: [2018, 0, 30, 23, 0, 0, 0] (7)
_d: Tue Jan 30 2018 23:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
_f: "DD/HH/YYYY HH:mm"
_i: "30/10/2018 23:00"
_isUTC: false
_l: undefined
```

which is not correct it should be **Tue Oct 30 2018 23:00:00 GMT_0200 (EET)**

I dont understand why the **Jan** Month appear.

> Moment version: ^2.1.0

Comment: Possibly related to this https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/

Comment: Check your `_f`  format string; you have an `HH` where the month should be, which is `MM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a error in your parse format.

`const notification = moment(weekDay + " " + time, "DD/HH/YYYY HH:mm");`

should be

`const notification = moment(weekDay + " " + time, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");`